# ModuleNotFoundError with package in path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following file structure

```
.
└── text_classifier
    ├── Experiment.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── hyperparameters
    │   ├── Hyperparameter.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── han.py
    │   └── model.py
    ├── trainers
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── dataset_trainer.py
    │   └── trainer.py
    └── utils
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── default_conf.yml
        ├── tf_utils.py
        └── utils.py
```

I want to `import text_classifier` from an Ipython console.

`text_classifier/__init__.py` contains

```
import builtins
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(__file__)

print('\n'.join(sys.path))

from .experiment import Experiment
from .hyperparameters import HP

try:
    from IPython.lib import deepreload

    builtins.reload = deepreload.reload
except:
    pass
```

However running `import text_classifier as tcl` from the same location as `text_classifier` yields the following:

```
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/victor/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/Users/victor/.ipython
/Users/victor/Documents/documentation
/Users/victor/Documents/documentation/han
/Users/victor/Documents/documentation/han/text_classifier
/Users/victor/Documents/documentation/han/text_classifier/__init__.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-256767c7aff3> in <module>()
----> 1 import text_classifier as tl

~/Documents/documentation/han/text_classifier/__init__.py in <module>()
    10 print('\n'.join(sys.path))
    11
---> 12 from .experiment import Experiment
    13 from .hyperparameters import HP
    14

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text_classifier.experiment'
```

Clearly, `text_classifier` is in the path (`...documentation/han/text_classifier`). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Experiment.py` module is with capital `E`, but you import the `experiment` that you dont have this module

```
.
└── text_classifier
    ├── Experiment.py
...
```

i think you need to import like this

```
# text_classifier/__init__.py
# if you have `Experiment` class
from .Experiment import Experiment

# or simple import `Experiment` module
from . import Experiment
```

Comment: Hahaha oh my god this is dumb AF. Cheers